# TIMESTAMP and NULL in Postgresql table

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to populate a database table in postgresql and just keep getting errors. The data is a customer data set with 15 columns all of which are of object type. The table is set to the following:

```
customer = ("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer (
CustID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
CustFName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CustLName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CustPhone VARCHAR(14),
CustEmail VARCHAR(275),
CustState CHAR(2),
ContactPref VARCHAR(10),
PmtID VARCHAR(20),
AddedStamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
UpdatedStamp TIMESTAMP,
HHI INT,
IsMarried CHAR(1),
HasKids CHAR(1),
TravelsWPet CHAR(1),
Pronoun VARCHAR(20));
""")

cursor.execute(customer)
conn.commit()
```

The data has instances in the updatedstamp column where it is blank and I need it to just put NULL in the table (no quotes, just the word), but when there is a date, I need it to put the date with quotes such as: '2015-01-01'.

Below is the latest attempt to get this to work:

```
import pandas as pd

custdf = pd.read_csv('customer.csv')

custdf = custdf.replace('NULL', None)

custdf['custid'] = custdf['custid'].astype(object)

for x in custdf.index:
    cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO customer (custid, custfname, custlname, custphone, custemail, custstate, contactpref, pmtid,
                      addedstamp, updatedstamp, hhi, ismarried, haskids, travelswpet, pronoun)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,
        IF(%s = 'NULL', NULL, '%s'), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
                   (custdf.loc[x]['custid'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['custfname'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['custlname'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['custphone'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['custemail'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['custstate'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['contactpref'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['pmtid'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['addedstamp'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['updatedstamp'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['hhi'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['ismarried'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['haskids'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['travelswpet'],
                    custdf.loc[x]['pronoun']))
    conn.commit()
    
query = ("""SELECT * FROM customer""")

customer_df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
print(customer_df)
```

This code returns `IndexError: tuple index out of range' - but the number of columns and placeholders are the same. Previous code attempts were giving me errors such as `InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NULL" LINE 4: ...l.com', 'AZ', 'call', 744905307847.0, '1/1/22 0:00', 'NULL',`

How can I fix this?

Comment: As you have used %s 16 times but only given 15 fields to fill them is potentially causing index out of range error. Try using `custdf.loc[x]['updatedstamp']` twice to indicate that %s is used twice for 1 column.

Comment: That doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you try your SQL statements before you put them in code. For example, there is no `IF` in the SQL language.

As you figured out, the error is caused by the quotes around NULL. There is, however, a deeper problem lurking underneath: By constructing a string literal with `execute("... '%s' ...", var)`, you make your code vulnerable to SQL injection. Use [the method provided by psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) to construct SQL strings in a safe way. That should also get rid of your immediate problem.

Comment: You have defined the columns `AddedStamp` and  `UpdatedStamp` with data type `timestamp`. Once you do that you no longer have control over how it is stored, Postgres will always use its internal structure. You can specify the format you want in later selects with [to_char](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).  Be careful with as you defined it as `not null`.